# package xkeyval error in ytableau package

Tags: errors, ytableau

I'm using the `ytableau` package to draw young tabs in Lyx. I loaded `ytableau` package in the preamble and I had no problems in drawing standard young tableaus/ferrers diagrams.

My problem is when I come to use the `tabloids` package option. Whenever I enter the command `tabloids` in the set up, for example:

```
\ytableausetup {boxsize=normal,tabloids}
\ytableaushort{ 123, 45, 6}
```

(lifted straight from the instructional pdf)

When I try to generate the pdf I get the error:

```
Package xkeyval error:'tabloids' undefined in families 'setup'.
```

Not sure what to do to remedy this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: This works fine for me.  You should make sure you have the most recent versions of the packages.

Answer (score 2):

Your error can't be reproduced by me. I am using TeX Live 2013.

The following [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) based on your code snippet works well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}

\ytableausetup {boxsize=normal,tabloids}
\ytableaushort{ 123, 45, 6}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I have the same problems with TeX Live 2013 ; I ran your example and I get the same error message as the OP. What do you suggest? Should I try to update something I might have missed? I don't know where to start.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Now I am using TeXLive 2014 and the example works also well.